# Are those two Sum-Of-Squares approach for unconstrained polynomial optimization related?

Tags: polynomial-hierarchy, semidefinite-programming, sum-of-squares

This is a crosspost of [mathoverflow/345282](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345282/)

I found 2 approaches to solve an unconstrained polynomial optimization problem using the Lasserre / SOS hierarchy:
$$\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\quad p(x)$$
where $p$ is a polynomial of even degree degree, $d=2\ell$.

1. The approach of Lasserre, which relies on Putinar's Nullstellensatz, requires to restrict to an archimedean domain, which can be done by adding the constraint $\|x\|^2\leq a$ for a sufficiently large $a$. This approach is described e.g. in Theorem 5.5. of [this lecture](https://inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/semi/optpast/FS07/opt_abs/PolynomialOptimization.pdf), and yields the hierarchy:

$$
\begin{align}\tag{$P_r$}
\sup &\quad \lambda\\
s.t. &\quad p(x)-\lambda = q(x) + \sigma(x) (a-\sum_i x_i^2)\\
     &\quad \text{for some SOS polynomials $p$,$\sigma$}\\
     &\quad \text{of degree at most $2(\ell+r)$ and $2(\ell+r-1)$, respectively.}
\end{align}
$$

2. The approach of Reznick, which is described e.g. in [this lecture](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hf323/lent2017_topics_convex_optimisation/lecture15.pdf), and consists in expressing $p(x)-p^*$ as a rational function (the ratio between a SOS polynomial and $(1+\|x\|^2)^r$ for increasing values of $r$):

$$
\begin{align}\tag{$Q_r$}
\sup &\quad \lambda\\
s.t. &\quad (1+\sum_i x_i^2)^r \ (p(x)-\lambda) = q(x)\\
     &\quad \text{for some SOS polynomials $p$ of degree $2(\ell+r).$}
\end{align}
$$

So my question is: Are these two approaches related / equivalent?  Is it known if one approach converges faster than the other one?